# How to separate my mouse and mouse in RDP?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server

I have an script that clicks on a button each minute to book something, and I want to run it in Windows Server, but the issue is when I minimize the RDP or close that, my script does not work anymore.

The issue is I think RDP uses my mouse and when I exit, it has no mouse either (not sure about keyboard, because the button cannot be booked with ENTER or like this, just should be clicked).

I saw [RDP: Using host's keyboard and mouse?](https://superuser.com/questions/639469/rdp-using-hosts-keyboard-and-mouse), but not sure it helps me because I see it says it shares between some sessions, while I want to have something `in-screen keyboard` of Windows, but for the Mouse.

Is there anyway to have something like virtual mouse or separate my mouse from Windows's session?

Comment: It's important to understand that if you're accessing the server via RDP then you are not actually running the script IN Windows Server.  You're running the script on your local client which sends mouse commands to the server via RDP.  That's very different.  RDP will only take your mouse and keyboard input while the window has focus.

Comment: @squillman thanks, I'm thinking of changing remote session timeouts and things like this to test if this is suitable for me.